# Blank and Beeping Control Panel for Gas Central Heater (Vulcan/Bonaire)

Tags: hvac, electrical-panel, heating, gas, heater

A few weeks ago, the control panel went blank and started beeping at a few second intervals. This would last a few minutes, then go off by itself, and would happen every other day. This was for the main control panel downstairs, but the upstairs panel was not affected. Do you know what the problem is? I've tried searching for Vulcan/Bonaire trouble shooting guides online, but could not find anything for this model. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do those panels have a battery?   Blank and beeping might mean a low/dead battery.

Comment: Which model is "this model"? If you pop the plastic cover off, there should be some stickers inside giving a specific model number. [Edit] that into your question, as it will help people help you.

Comment: Hi @crip659, i've uploaded some photos of what's behind the cover. Do you know which one is the battery?

Comment: Does not seem to have a battery, but does seem to have blown capacitors.  The black tube thingy above the orange circle on the left side.  Might need to be replaced, I do not know enough about them.